# Confluent Cloud Kafka Go v2.1.1 : ssl/certs and unregistered scheme error

Tags: go, ssl-certificate, sasl, confluent-kafka-go

We have recently upgraded from v1 to v2 of the library. We are encountering the below errors in our bootstrap logs:

`sasl_ssl://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa.confluent.cloud:9092/bootstrap: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory: calling stat(/usr/lib/ssl/certs)`

`sasl_ssl://xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa.confluent.cloud:9092/bootstrap: error:16000069:STORE routines::unregistered scheme: scheme=file`

How to reproduce
Kafka consumer deployed using Docker.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.20.4-alpine3.17 AS builder
RUN apk add --no-progress --no-cache bash ca-certificates gcc musl-dev
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .
RUN go mod download

RUN go build -tags musl -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' -o /build/kafka-consumers

FROM scratch
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /build/kafka-consumers .
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/kafka-consumers"]
```

confluent-kafka-go v2.1.1

confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.4.0

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. The issue was resolved by downgrading the confluent-kafka-go version to v1.9.2.